# PHP Error with array_merge in Pusher Second param is null

Tags: php, laravel-6, pusher, php-7.2

I´m trying to send a push notification in Laravel. I´m using pusher but there is an error.

**route.web**

```
Route::get('push', function () {
    event(new App\Events\MessageToProveedor("Welcome"));
    return "Event has been sent!";
})->name('push');
```

**MessageToProveedor's file**

```
public $username;

public $message;
/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->message  = "liked your status";
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    //channel
    return ['my-channel'];
}
public function broadcastAs()
{
    //event
    return 'my-event';
}
```

When I execute de route /push return an error in Pusher.php plugin.

```
ErrorException array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array
```

**Failing line**
$all_params = array_merge($post_params,$params);

$params is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Laravel v8.29.0? This should be resolved in that release.

Comment: I´m using laravel v6.18.35

Comment: You will either need to upgrade to the version specified, or downgrade the version of the pusher-http-php (`composer require pusher/pusher-php-server ^4.1`)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works with `composer require pusher/pusher-php-server ^4.1`